# Pivot table pulling from another excel file not updating when the file is updated

Tags: microsoft-excel, multiple-users, pivot-chart

I have two excel files.  One has all the data that is entered by multiple people periodically thru out the day.  The second one pulls data from the first file and then a pivot chart is created.  If both are opened by one user the pivot table updates automatically.  If one person has the data one open and someone else has the pivot table one open no updates happen tot the pivot chart.  I realize the data one must be saved and then the second one with the pivot table must be refreshed..what is the quickest and easiest way to do this..

Answer (score 0):

There are limitations to using Excel as a database for multiple users and your example is one of them.  (see also [one-excel-file-multiple-editing-users-live-updates](https://superuser.com/questions/731723/one-excel-file-multiple-editing-users-live-updates))

As a kludge/workaround I'd recommend the following:

1) in the 'data' workbook, some VBA code to the worksheet's module to auto save the Workbook when a new "entry" has been recorded.  Something like the example will work, but replace "C:C" with the column where you want the save to occur.  This is just so it doesn't save  when every field is completed, only on one of them.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then 
End Sub
```

2) in the pivot-table & pivot-chart workbook

a) Add VBA code to `ThisWorkbook` module to automatically open the data workbook, like the following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
        Workbooks.Open "C:\My Documents\Data_Workbook.xlsm"
End Sub
```

b) set to auto-refresh on opening as per the image below.  Obviously you will need to have the 'data' workbook open, even if it is only in read-only mode.  (You could obviously write some VBA code for this as well but I've tried to minimise that)

[image]

It's not elegant but then again using Excel as a database is a compromise from the start.